# How are irreps connected when lowering symmetry?

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, symmetry

The following question arises naturally in physical contexts when you measure things in a system of certain symmetry $G$ which eventually becomes distorted to lower symmetry $H_a$. There is plenty of information and research on this process but afaics no thorough mathematical description of it, which is parsed smoothly by a mathematician. Typical terms in this context are "Peirls distortion" or "Jahn-Teller effect". In attempting such a formulation, the below formulated question occurs. It takes however some effort to formulate the whole setting as I have experienced, so I must start with a:

Definition (**epikernel** and **kernel**):

The epikernel of a group $G$ with respect to an irreducible subspace of $V^{(i)}$ of a representation $V$ of $G$ is $$ \mathrm{Epi}(G,V^{(i)}):=\{\mathrm{Stab_G}(v)| v\in V^{(i)}\},$$ and the kernel $\mathrm{Ke}(G,V^{(i)})$ is the intersection of all elements of this respective epikernel and $\mathrm{Stab_G}(v)$ is the [stabilizer group](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/stabilizer+group) of $v$.

We can define a (non-surjective) map from the set containing $G$ onto the set of all subgroups of $G$

$$ \varphi_{i}: G\mapsto H_{a}\in \mathrm{Epi}(G,V^{(i)}), $$ which is either well defined as it is (if the epikernel contains only one set) or in other cases we can choose one element $H_{a}$. In the latter case there is a bijection from $H_a$ to the maximal subspace $V_a^{(i)}\subset V^{(i)}, $ for which we have 
$$ \{H_a\} = \{\mathrm{Stab_G}(v)| v\in V_a^{(i)}\},$$

$\varphi_i$ is a map from $G$ to the set of its subgroups corresponding to the irreducible representation with Index $i$. This map is in the context of symmetry-breaking (Jahn-Teller distortion) also called descent in symmetry from $G$ to $H_a$ in direction of $V_a^{(i)}$ (or simply distortion in $V_a^{(i)}$-direction).

The question now is if it is possible to track the action of $\varphi_i$ on the irreducible representations when going from $G$ to $H_a$? Namely:

**Is there a generic relation between the irreps of $G$ and $H_a$ in the distortion, which indicates which irrep becomes which or came from which?**

and in particular

**Can we trace such a relation in the case of a "splitting" of a *non-one-dimensional or complex* irrep of $G$ into lower-dimensional irreps of $H_a$, in case this takes place.**

I know that there will be difficulties, such as for example in

$$\mathrm{Epi}(D_4,E)=\{C_2^{(a)},C_2^{(b)}\} $$

we yield two differently oriented $C_2$ groups I have called these orientations $(a)$ and $(b)$, but here it turns out that in both cases $E$ splits into $A\oplus B$. (While in the standard orientation, that is, the main axis of $D_4$ and $C_2$ oriented in the same direction $B\oplus B $ would combine to $E$ when adding elements to $C_2$ to get $D_4$). So in this example the relation we search for would be 
$$E[D_4]\to(A,B)[C_2].$$
On the other side physical intuition clearly shows that such a tracing of irreps during distortion must be possible (that argument should hold at least for subgroups of SO(3)).

Any suggestiones?

Comment: I am completely totally lost at the "we can define a map ...", because then none of the type of anything later makes any sense. I don't know if the domain of $\phi_i$ is $\{G\}$ or $G$, if its target set is $Epi(G,V_i)$ or the set of subgroups of $G$, I don't know how $H_a$ can both be a subgroup of $G$ and a set of subgroups of $G$, I don't know how there can be a bijection from $H_a$ which I assume is finite (is $G$ finite ?) and a whole subspace, etc etc

Comment: @mercio: Where do you read that $H_a$ is a set of subgroups of $G$?

Comment: when you write $H_a = \{\operatorname{Stab}_G(v) \mid v \in V_a^{(i)}\}$